# Laravel Eloquent create related item doesnt save

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I encounterd a strange issue / bug today.

I have an orders table and a table for the assigned products (order_items)
Everything works fine when creating a new order, the items are saved as they should be.

```
$order = Orders::create($request->all());

if (!empty($order)) {
    foreach ($request->get('items') as $item) {
        $item['order_id'] = $order->id;
        OrderItems::create($item);
    }
}
```

The issue is that I can't add items later on, for whatever reason.
I'm not getting any errors or wrong responses, even the auto-increment of the order_items table increases.

```
Orders::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());

if(isset($data['items']) && is_array($data['items'])) {
    foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
        if (!empty($item['id'])) {
            OrderItems::findOrFail($item['id'])->update($item);
            continue;
        }

        $item['order_id'] = $id;
        OrderItems::create($item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your item is not found, this will throw an exception and exuction of your script will halt.

```
OrderItems::findOrFail($item['id'])->update($item);
```

You need to catch the exception like this:

```
try {
    OrderItems::findOrFail($item['id'])->update($item);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
    $item['order_id'] = $id;
    OrderItems::create($item);
}
```

Comment: i know that, but thats what what my issue is.
the additional item comes without an Id the issue is that  OrderItems::create($item); doesnt save the item but still increases the auto-increment of the table, im not sure if that is and issue due to the relations with the orders table but than the initial creation shouldnt work either. Im not getting any errors, i even get the correct response from OrderItems::create($item);

Comment: are your fields $fillable or protected in your model?  also can you dd($request->all); to see what is trying to be saved to order

Comment: i checked everything i could, it doesnt make any sense maybe it is an mysql issue.
yes every field i need to fill is in $fillable, and if not, the initial creation wouldnt work either.

Comment: does the `->update($item)` bit update the data in the DB @ChristianReinelt